# Solaris SMF: Kill with custom signal, or get PID, or prevent kill of children

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, smf

In the Solaris Service XML

I am using a kill to signal a graceful shutdown

```
<exec_method type="method" name="stop" exec=":kill" timeout_seconds="60" />
```

This works great, except for the fact that it also kills the child processes, which mostly just die after a SIGTERM. Any of these will work

- Get the PID so I can use `exec="kill -SIGUSR1 $PID"`
- Prevent SIGTERM from being sent to the children. (or at least not the grandchildren)
- Use some other signal

I would prefer not to set up a separate script that has to go figure out the pid. I will do this if I have to. I would prefer to get it from an environment variable, or use a SMF built in command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec=":kill -USR1"` does the trick.  Without `SIG`.

I was looking for this when defining `method="refresh"`.  jperkin set me straight with his example of `exec=":kill -HUP"`, whereas on SmartOS using `exec=":kill -SIGHUP"` resulted in `"/sbin/sh[1]: exec: :kill: not found"`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can just do `exec="kill -SIGUSR1"`.

Comment: I get in the svc log: `/usr/bin/kill[8]: kill: bad option(s)`.

Comment: Err I meant `exec=":kill -SIGUSR1"` - not sure if you caught that. :(

Comment: I get `/sbin/sh: :kill: not found`. Sorry. If only there was a way not to propagate the kill to the children! That would make it so easy!

Answer (score 0):

This is because both parent and child are under same contract ("man contract" for more info)

Make use of "ctrun" ("man ctrun" for more info), this will create child process under different contract. 
Doing this will prevent child from getting killed when parent is being killed.